# Webpack: generate multiple outputs using one entry

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to generate multiple versions of my entry file. I.e. `webpack.config.js` contains:

```
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve('./src/main.js'),
    main2: path.resolve('./src/main.js'),
  },
```

Within `main.js`, I can do:

```
if (entryName === 'main') {
  ...
} else if (entryName === 'main2') {
  ...
}
```

Is this possible using Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using different run scripts that set an environment variable (using [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)) which is interpolated at compilation using [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

Run scripts:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:main": "cross-env ENTRY_NAME=main webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:main2": "cross-env ENTRY_NAME=main2 webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build": "npm run build:main && npm run build:main2"
  }
}
```

Webpack:

```
{
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve('./src/main.js')
  },
  plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
      ENTRY_NAME: JSON.stringify(process.env.ENTRY_NAME)
    })
  ]
}
```

Application:

```
if (ENTRY_NAME === 'main') {
  //...
} else if (ENTRY_NAME === 'main2') {
  //...
}
```